# Test class within node.js, mock requests

Tags: node.js, request, mocking, jestjs

I have following class:

```
class QueueRequest{

  constructor(){
    this.queue = [];
  }

  async getKeepAliveRequestLibrary(httpOptions){
    //creation of special type of request with Keep-Alive
    const httpModule = (airConf.useSecureConnection ? https : http);
    const keepAliveRequest = request.defaults({
      agent: new httpModule.Agent({
        keepAlive: true,
        maxSockets: airConf.maxSockets,
      })
    });
    let response = await keepAliveRequest(httpOptions);

    return response;
  }

  async addRequestToQueue(httpOptions){

    this.queue.push(httpOptions);
    let response = await this.getKeepAliveRequestLibrary(this.queue[0]);
    this.queue.shift();

    return response;
  }

}

module.exports = QueueRequest;
```

I try to test the class in following way:

```
const sinon = require('sinon');
const rp = require('request-promise-native');
//override the original common, so we can manipulate the config
jest.mock('./common');

//local dependencies
require('./common').prepareConfigForTaskHandler(13);

const QueueRequest = require('./queue-request');

let queue = new QueueRequest();


describe('Testing QueueRequest module:', () => {
  //setup
  it('checking proper queueing one request', () => {
    sinon.stub(rp, 'Request').resolves({});

    //test

  });

  //teardown
  it('checking proper queueing many requests', () => {

  });

});
```

My issue is to test module as a whole class. My intention is to test without making a real requests. I want to have two test, one test for only one test, and second for many tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mock request with Nock (https://github.com/nock/nock). You can specify url, headers and reponse expectation.
Eg:
I want to mock a GET request to a service, and I expect a specific payload as response with statusCode 200.

```
nock(baseUrl, {reqheaders: {"Authorization": "Bearer <token>"}}.get(path).reply(200, {result:{ "Id": 1}})
```